# Prove ${-1 \choose n} = (-1)^n$

Tags: summation

For my Math Physics homework, I have to show that ${-1\choose n} = (-1)^n$. I read the textbook (no help) and this wasn't covered in lecture, I have no idea where to even begin. Please help.

Comment: How do you define $\binom{-1}{n}$?

Comment: The standard (and really the only sensible) way to define ${m\choose n}$ for any real $m$ is  ${m\choose n} = \frac{m(m-1)\ldots (m-n+1)}{n!}$

Answer (score 5):

With positive integers, one can say things like
$$
\binom 8 3 = \frac{8!}{3!5!}.
$$
By canceling $5!$ one can say
$$
\binom 8 3 = \frac{8\cdot7\cdot6}{3\cdot2\cdot1}.
$$
This latter form works if in place of $8$ we put a number that is not a nonnegative integer, even if we have not defined factorials for those:
$$
\binom{8.1}3 = \frac{(8.1)(7.1)(6.1)}{3\cdot2\cdot1}.
$$
This can be applied to negative integers:
$$
\binom{-8}{3} = \frac{(-8)(-9)(-10)}{3\cdot2\cdot1}.
$$
So we have
$$
\binom{-1}3 = \frac{(-1)(-2)(-3)}{3\cdot2\cdot1}.
$$
Now think about what happens if $n=3$ is changed to $n=\text{some other positive integer}$.

The number
$$
\left|\binom{-8}{3}\right| = \left|\frac{(-8)(-9)(-10)}{3\cdot2\cdot1}\right|
$$
is how many sub-multisets of size $3$ are in a set of size $8$.  I've seen it expressed loosely as "negative sets are multisets".

Comment: Thanks! This didn't give me the answer, but it allowed me to find it, just perfect.